# how to run a python script many times while read two input files

Tags: python

I have a python script which get three inputs: it should read a fits file (fil1.fits, file2.fits ,...) and get variable "A" and "B" from a csv file (name.csv); first column is "A" and the second one is "B". All fits files and scv file are in a same folder. Briefly, my code is like:

```
def kinematic():

    file = 'Desktop/data/test/spec-001.fits'
    hdu = fits.open(file)
    Flux = 'flux'
    A = 2.31
    B = optic
    # here is what the script does ...
    # here is what the script does ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kinematics()
```

could you please guide me how I can run it for many inputs simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below same code to import the multiple files at one go from same folder:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("*.fits") # get all the file names
for file in files:
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        lines=read(f)   # depending on the file format you can use different function for reading file and then parse it.
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but I got this error: OSError: File-like object does not have a 'write' method, required for mode 'ostream'.

Comment: I added arguments to the function and now it works! thanks for your help.